# Flutter use it SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAH74.png)
when i don't use SingleChildScrollView did that but when i used the[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlYYC.png)

how solve it ??

SingleChildScroll view use it and don't use it
The result did not change even if I entered it as a video card media query or by giving a value myself.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the column

```
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
```

> MainAxisSize.min Row and Column only occupy enough space on their main
> axes for their children. Their children are laid out without extra
> space and at the middle of their main axes.

The explanation is from flutter docs for more info you can check this [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/codelabs/layout-basics#mainaxissize-property)

Answer (score 0):

You can add

`mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`

parameter to the Column and do not use any expandable element inside Column, if you use it it will throw renderflex errors.

Other fix you can do is wrap column with SizedBox and set height to the screen height or any size you want, and than wrap that SizedBox with `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: Now i can scroll but pixels error during